# Transition of one layer with multiple background layers

Tags: css, input, background, transition, layer

I have an imput field in form with multiple(two) backgrounds like this:

```
background: url(framework/images/search.png) no-repeat 6px 7px, 
/*this is a magnifying glass icon - this is important later */
                rgba(200,200,200,0.1);
```

Then I've got a transition:

```
transition:background 0.2s linear, box-shadow 0.5s linear;
```

And on focus of the input field:

```
input:focus, {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
}
```

Basically what it does (or should) is when the input field is active the background changes to slightly darker color with transitions. Also box shadow makes an inner effect of inside border. That was the case when background was of one element (only background color). Now when I added icon on higher layer the background wont change, but box-shadow works. I think that browser is confused how to change color of bitmap image.

My question is: Is there a way to transition only one layer of background (address it somehow), so that the bitmap image will stay the same and the color will change?

Thank you.

EDIT: Jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/8DRTt/

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: Here, I hope You could help me. http://jsfiddle.net/8DRTt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8DRTt/1/

```
input:focus, #two:focus {...}
```

the problem was the selector.

The `#two` selector is stronger than the input:focus selector, thus overiding the background property.

When you add `#two:focus` to the selector of the darker background, it can no longer be overridden.

Comment: Your solution helped me to understand the problem. I have come out with something a bit different Here is how it was ment to be. http://jsfiddle.net/QVarf/